# How to toggle the mat-toggle-button based on user input as well as toggle-button?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I was trying to use the toggle button into my project, but I found myself stuck in the following case:

What if the toggle button needs to be controlled based on the value the server gives?

Here is my code that I was implementing.

```html
<mat-button-toggle-group name="fontStyle" [value]="selectedVal" #group="matButtonToggleGroup" (change)="onValChange(group.value)" aria-label="Font Style">
  <mat-button-toggle value="true">True</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="false">False</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
<div>
  [animation] = <span>{{selectedVal}}</span>
</div>
```

Here is my TS file where I am getting the value of the selected value from the button toggle.

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Basic button-toggles
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'button-toggle-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'button-toggle-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['button-toggle-overview-example.css'],
})
export class ButtonToggleOverviewExample {
  selectedVal:string;
  
  onValChange(val: string) {
    this.selectedVal = val;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't make a snippet of code which isn't running. Either make a stackblitz demo or just put it as code formatted.

Comment: sure, @Mukyuu, I am making stackblitz demo. and soon I will share it.

Comment: Really i didn't understand your problem?
Can you explain more?
I can help you ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change value="selectedVal" instead of [value]="selectedVal"

```
<mat-button-toggle-group name="fontStyle" value="selectedVal" #group="matButtonToggleGroup" (change)="onValChange(group.value)" aria-label="Font Style">
  <mat-button-toggle value="true">True</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="false">False</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```